# ADT Bundle for mac is damaged

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, adt

I download the [ADT Bundle for mac](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and save it under `/development`. When I try to open eclipse, my mac says `"Eclipse" is damaged and can't be opened. You should move it to the Trash`. I trash the whole thing and tried downloading again, I get the same error. Does anyone know a fix for this? My mac is osx 10.8.3 processor 3.1 GHz Intel Core i5.

FYI: I removed an old eclipse folder from `/Application` before doing above. Could the older deleted juno eclipse (Version: Juno Service Release 2) be causing some interference?

Comment: Did you verify the downloaded file checksum with `md5sum adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130219.zip` ? You should get the result **b768c28f380c1846479664c4790e9c53**. Then I guess you need to unzip it if MacOS doesn't do it automatically somehow.

Comment: I was wondering about that, but I saw no checksum on the site. Where did you find that checksum? do you have a link?

Comment: Anyway, I did `openssl md5 adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130219.zip` and got `MD5(adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130219.zip)= b768c28f380c1846479664c4790e9c53`

Comment: The MD5 Checksum is available on the page in the link you provided :-)

Comment: So, the zipfile has been downloaded correctly and is not corrupt, then it might very well be that the individual file `Eclipse` is damaged (before it was zipped), so guess someone else with a Mac that uses the ADT Bundle needs to help you verify it.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Any resolution ?

Answer (score 13):

This bug is related to the signing of the app and [Gatekeeper](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5290).

> "Damaged" app. – The app has been altered by something other than the
>   developer.

The bug is also reported in [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398450)

An easy fix (as suggested by #2 comment in the above bug report) is disabling Gatekeeper temporarily. Visit System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Select "Anywhere" in "Allow Applications downloaded from:". Now run the app and you can enable Gatekeeper again.

Answer (score 5):

I found a workaround [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398450), in the command line go to the directory containing the Elicpse.app directory and execute

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine Eclipse.app/
```

the problem seems not to be solved anyway